# Is the IP address 192.169.0.135 valid for local/private or public host?

Tags: ipv4

Please, I need to know if the IP  IP 192.169.0.135 can be used... as a local/private or public host?

There are different rules to local/private ips?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See [RFC 1918, Address Allocation for Private Internets](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) for the three private address ranges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

192.169.0.135 is a valid public address.

There are several tools on the web that allow you to look up addresses to find out to whom they're assigned.  For example, a WHOIS search returns:

```
IP owner info (Whois): "192.169.0.135"



#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#


#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# https://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=192.169.0.135?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&showNonArinTopLevelNet=false&ext=netref2
#

NetRange:       192.169.0.0 - 192.169.1.255
CIDR:           192.169.0.0/23
NetName:        PSG169
NetHandle:      NET-192-169-0-0-1
Parent:         NET192 (NET-192-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Assignment
OriginAS:       
Organization:   RGnet, LLC (RGNETI-1)
RegDate:        2005-04-12
Updated:        2014-03-28
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-192-169-0-0-1


OrgName:        RGnet, LLC
OrgId:          RGNETI-1
Address:        5147 Crystal Spring
City:           Bainbridge Island
StateProv:      WA
PostalCode:     98110
Country:        US
RegDate:        1990-10-01
Updated:        2011-09-24
Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/RGNETI-1


OrgAbuseHandle: RB366-ARIN
OrgAbuseName:   Bush, Randy 
OrgAbusePhone:  +1-206-780-0431 
OrgAbuseEmail:  randy@psg.com
OrgAbuseRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/RB366-ARIN

OrgTechHandle: RB366-ARIN
OrgTechName:   Bush, Randy 
OrgTechPhone:  +1-206-780-0431 
OrgTechEmail:  randy@psg.com
OrgTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/RB366-ARIN

RTechHandle: RB366-ARIN
RTechName:   Bush, Randy 
RTechPhone:  +1-206-780-0431 
RTechEmail:  randy@psg.com
RTechRef:    https://whois.arin.net/rest/poc/RB366-ARIN


#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
# If you see inaccuracies in the results, please report at
# https://www.arin.net/public/whoisinaccuracy/index.xhtml
#
```

Answer (score 2):

Private IP ranges:

10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 /8
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 /12
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 /16

192.169.0.135 does not fall in those specified ranges so most likely it is a Public IP

Comment: Just because an IP address is not in one of the private address ranges does not mean it is a public address. There are other ranges which cannot be globally routed, and so they are not public addresses. See [IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml).

Comment: Yes i know. I should have been more clear. thanks for pointing that out